# Почему сохраняет неверные данные даже при ajaxValidationUrl?

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

У меня есть поле, которое валидируется через `enableAjaxValidation`. У формы стоит `validationUrl`, который возвращает ошибки. Всё работает. Однако, если проигнорировать все эти сообщения и нажать кнопку "submit", то данные все сохранятся, т.к. валидации в экшне сохранения уже нет. Как быть?

Мне нужно, чтобы даже при клике на submit провалидировались данные и только потом произошла отправка формы на сохранение

---

Экшн

```
public function actionUpdate(int $id) {
    $componentModel = Component::findOne(['id' => $id]);

    if ($componentModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $componentModel->save(false)) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $componentModel->id], 200);
    }

    $renderData = [
        'model' => $componentModel,            
    ];

    return Yii::$app->request->isAjax ? $this->renderAjax('update', $renderData) : $this->render('update', $renderData);  
}
```

валидация

```
public function actionValidate(int $id) {
    $componentModel = Component::findOne(['id' => $id]);    
    $componentModel->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post()['Component'];    
    
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    
    if (!$componentModel->validate())
        return ActiveForm::validate($componentModel);
    
    return [];
}
```

форма

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'component-form',
    'action' => Url::to(['/physical-node/update', 'id' => $componentModel->id]),
    'options' => [
        'data-pjax' => 1
    ],
    'validationUrl' => Url::to(['/physical-node/validate', 'id' => $componentModel->id]),
]); ?>


// ...
// ...
// ...
// ...
```

Comment: Не важно что на фронте, на сервере всегда должна быть валидация данных. Это надо запомнить навсегда. Если надо на фронте валидировать, то можно добавить функцию, которая будет вызываться по submit формы.

Comment: @fedornabilkin при валидировании в экшне, и при наличии `enableAjaxValidation`  в поле - происходит автосохранение. И это очень плохо

Comment: Продемонстрируйте ваш код по части екшена validationUrl и екшена на сохранению уже валидных данных.

Comment: @UKRman добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

При субмите в екшене тоже делайте валидацию, почему вы ее отключили, можете добавить к форме атрибут **validateOnSubmit** в true. Но ваш екшен при субмите изменить нужно:

```
public function actionUpdate(int $id) {
    $componentModel = Component::findOne($id);

    if ($componentModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $componentModel->validate()) { // или $componentModel->save()
        $componentModel->save(false);

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $componentModel->id], 200);
    }

    $renderData = [
        'model' => $componentModel,            
    ];

    return Yii::$app->request->isAjax ? $this->renderAjax('update', $renderData) : $this->render('update', $renderData);  
}
```

Comment: "делайте валидацию, почему вы ее отключили, " -- ну я подумал, если у меня есть `validationUrl`, который отвечает за валидацию, то тогда зачем второй раз её прописывать в экшнее? А экшн сделать чище. В этом была идея. А какой смысл дубля?

Comment: Да, а отключить js на странице, то смысл сразу обретается.

Comment: Можно ведь данные отправить и не со страницы.

Comment: Ну если вы отключить csrf валидацию, то да у вас получиться отослать данные не со станицы формы, и в таком случае, да нужно валидировать данные

Comment: @UKRman если отключить js то даже страница не загрузится) Ну предположим, что js всегда включен. И работа только с сайтом. без консоли, без curl и пр. То смысл есть?